# Changing colour at column number

Tags: bash

I have a multiline string to print the beginning of each line with blue foreground, whereas the rest of each line uses a white foreground.  The user would define a column number from which the foreground colour on each line changes to white.

```
str="
 marinex-dgrul-blue    Digit-white
 marinex-ltrul-blue    Letter-white
 marinex-nmrul-blue    Numeric-white"
```

Then I would call my function

```
marinex-ndic 23 "$str"
```

Starting from column number `23`, the text colour gets changed from blue to white.

```
marinex-ndic ()
 {
  ## Show coloured  and label

  local -r rst="$( tput sgr0 )"  # Default Graphic Rendition
  local -r blu="$( tput bold; tput setaf 39 )"  # BLUE
  local -r wht="$( tput bold; tput setaf 15 )"  # WHITE

  printf '%s\n' "$@"  \
    | while IFS="" read -r vl; do
        printf '%s%s%s%s%s\n' "${blu}" "$vla" "$wht" "$vlb" "${rst}"
      done
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the current code works correctly (eg, prints correct colors, reads input lines into `vl`, etc) in OP's env ...

We can use `bash` substrings to split the `$vl` variable:

```
marinex-ndic ()
 {
  local col="$1"            # save columnm number
  shift                     # shift input params (ie, remove 'col' from $@)
  
  local -r rst="$( tput sgr0 )"  # Default Graphic Rendition
  local -r blu="$( tput bold; tput setaf 39 )"  # BLUE
  local -r wht="$( tput bold; tput setaf 15 )"  # WHITE

  printf '%s\n' "$@"  \
    | while IFS="" read -r vl; do
        printf '%s%s%s%s%s\n' "${blu}" "${vl:0:col}" "$wht" "${vl:col}" "${rst}"
        #                               ^^^^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^
      done
 }
```

**NOTES:**

- this particular blue color code (`blu`) is not working in my env; I'm assuming these colors work in OP's env so I haven't attempted to address actual color codes
- OP can decide if additional logic should be added to the function to verify `$1` is a positive integer

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet will help you change the foreground colour at a specific column number:

`printf '%s%s%s%s%s\n' "${blu}" "$vl" "$wht" "$vl" "${rst}" | while IFS="" read -r`

Comment: How does it help ?  `vl` is simply the whole line.  But I want to split it so that the first `vla` is blue and `vlb` is white.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use cut & paste:

```
#!/bin/bash

marinex-ndic () {
  local -r col="$1"
  local -r str="$2"
  local -r colp1=$((col+1))
  local -r rst="$( tput sgr0 )"  # Default Graphic Rendition
  local -r blu="$( tput bold; tput setaf 39 )"  # BLUE
  local -r wht="$( tput bold; tput setaf 15 )"  # WHITE

  paste <(cut -c-${col} <<<"$str" | sed "s/^/${blu}/;s/$/${rst}/")  <(cut -c${colp1}- <<<"$str" | sed "s/^/${wht}/;s/$/${rst}/")
}

str="
 marinex-dgrul-blue    Digit-white
 marinex-ltrul-blue    Letter-white
 marinex-nmrul-blue    Numeric-white"

marinex-ndic 23 "$str"
```